# Use different set of validators based on attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm struggling with a particular concept with Rails model validations, allow me to explain; I have a situation where a given user can be in several different `states`, based upon which, I'd like to use an entirely different set of validators on the model, and *only* validate the model with these validators.

Say for example my users could be in one of two `states`, 'address_setup', and 'billing_setup', I'd like to have two entirely different set of validators, can I somehow use a block like this?

```
with_options if self.state == 'address_setup' do |user|
  user.validates :first_name, :last_name, :address_1, :city, :state_code, :email
  user.validates :state_code, inclusion: { :in => STATE_CODES }
end
```

Obviously the `if` part of the `with_options` block doesn't make any sense, what is the best practices way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the `if` option in validator? For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validates :state_code, inclusion: { :in => STATE_CODES },
            if: Proc.new { |u| u.state == 'address_setup' }
  # ...
end
```